# Issue when using ScreeManager with Kivy- buttons layout no longer works

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

So I am having an issue with trying to use screen manager. Since I have to create my screen classes to now be (Screen) instead of (GridLayout) to use screenmanager at all, for instance, the button/layout management can't be controlled in python anymore? It used to lay out 5 columns and 3 rows for a total of 15 buttons on screen. Now it just shows one large one with (Screen) instead of grid layout.

```
class LandingScreen(Screen):
def build(self):
    return presentation
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = 5
    self.buttons = []  # add references to all buttons here

    # Loop to make 20 different buttons on screen
    for x in range(15):
        self.buttons.append(Button(text='button ' + str(x)))  # make a reference to the button before adding it in
        self.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
        self.buttons[x].background_normal = 'YOUTUBE.png'
```

where the buttons and column setup here used to create 3 rows of 5 buttons using this loop, it does not since I added (Screen) to the class instead of (GridLayout). I would rather not create all the buttons in the .kv file, since I think it's easier to manage in the .py and makes more sense to me.

Here is my .kv file:

```
<GridLayout>:
    cols: 5
    height: 480
    width: 800
    spacing: 25, 20
    padding: 25,25

<MyScreenManager>:
    LandingScreen:
    InputScreen:

<InputScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:

<LandingScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 5
        height: 480
        width: 800
        spacing: 25, 20
        padding: 25,25
```

It's obviously redundant because I was trying to figure out how to make all 15 buttons show again, not just the one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the buttons to `GridLayout` inside `Screen`, not to `Screen` directly. To do this, use an `id` to refer to the `GridLayout`.

However, you can not use ids inside `__init__` method because the rules defined in the kv file are not applied until the corresponding widget is fully initialized. The solution is correctly provided by Ryan Pi in this question:

[Why can't I access the Screen.ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26916262/7131499)

On the other hand, to change screen later you must define **name** property in yours screens.

Your code should be:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock


kv_text='''\

<MyScreenManager>:
    LandingScreen:
    InputScreen:

<InputScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'input_sc'
    AnchorLayout:
        id: anchor_1

<LandingScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'landing_sc'
    GridLayout:
        id: grid_1
        cols: 5
        height: 480
        width: 800
        spacing: 25, 20
        padding: 25,25
'''

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LandingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buttons = [] # add references to all buttons here
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def _finish_init(self, dt):
        self.ids.grid_1.cols = 5

        # Loop to make 20 different buttons on screen
        for x in range(15):
            self.buttons.append(Button(text='button {}'.format(x)))
            self.ids.grid_1.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
            self.buttons[x].background_normal = 'YOUTUBE.png'

class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyKivyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to use `Properties` instead of the `ids` method (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)), you should do something like:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


kv_text='''\

<MyScreenManager>:
    LandingScreen:
    InputScreen:

<InputScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'input_sc'
    AnchorLayout:
        id: anchor_1

<LandingScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'landing_sc'
    grid_1: grid_1
    GridLayout:
        id: grid_1
        cols: 5
        height: 480
        width: 800
        spacing: 25, 20
        padding: 25,25
'''

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LandingScreen(Screen):

    grid_1 = ObjectProperty(None)    #<<<< Propertie

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buttons = [] # add references to all buttons here
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def _finish_init(self, dt):
        self.grid_1.cols = 5
        # Loop to make 20 different buttons on screen
        for x in range(15):
            self.buttons.append(Button(text='button{}'.format(x)))
            self.grid_1.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
            self.buttons[x].background_normal = 'star.png'

class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyKivyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response. So as far as the self.ids.grid_1.cols part goes- can basically any kivy functionality be edited in the .py file in this manner?

Comment: @Austin , Ids allow you to reference any widget and use its methods / attributes in python. See https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a fundamental part of kivy that I wasn't grasping. This makes things easier in a lot of regards now.